# Why is javaw loading files and not eclipse.exe?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have two windows 7 profiles with eclipse installed.

1. Profile 1 loads fine
2. profile 2 throws plugin failed to load

I ran procmon to compare the two. In profile 1 eclipse.exe is the process attempting to load my jar. For profile 2 I notice javaw.exe is trying to load my jar and it's never called by eclipse.exe?

What would cause javaw.exe to access my jar in profile 2 instead of eclipse.exe?

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse will launch javaw, so the real process is javaw.exe. Some application could betterly wrap java applications. So you could see only the application process not java or javaw. Take a look at launch4j.